# Why is this rails form not finding the correct path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

So I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why this isn't working. I keep getting

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `admin_information_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc67971cab8>:0x007fc67d775740>
```

With the trace:

```
 # ./app/views/admin/informations/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_admin_informations__form_html_erb__2815737811953353352_70245242566200'
 # ./app/views/admin/informations/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_admin_informations_new_html_erb___3700624853666844924_70245242606040'
```

Any tips in the right direction?

---

My routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :informations
end
```

My controller:

```
class Admin::InformationsController < Admin::AdminController
  def new
    @information = Information.new
  end
end
```

views/admin/informations/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Add New Information Page</h1>
<%= render :partial => 'form', locals: { information: @information } %>
```

views/admin/informations/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, information] do |f| %>
    <%= error_messages_for information %>

    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br><br>

    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %><br><br>

    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

---

Output of `rake routes`

```
    admin_informations GET    /admin/informations(.:format)           admin/informations#index
                       POST   /admin/informations(.:format)           admin/informations#create
 new_admin_information GET    /admin/informations/new(.:format)       admin/informations#new
edit_admin_information GET    /admin/informations/:id/edit(.:format)  admin/informations#edit
     admin_information GET    /admin/informations/:id(.:format)       admin/informations#show
                       PUT    /admin/informations/:id(.:format)       admin/informations#update
                       DELETE /admin/informations/:id(.:format)       admin/informations#destroy
            admin_root        /admin(.:format)                        admin/sessions#new
```

Comment: Do you have a route for "admin_information_index_path"? That might explain why it thinks the helper method is undefined.

Comment: the form shouldn't even be trying to access that method. It should be accessing either the new or edit methods... weird stuff.

Comment: If you were getting this error when the form was submitted, I'd say that there is some default controller logic that is constructing a weird route that doesn't exist (especially if you don't have create defined in your controller, but I assume you just left that out of the post). If you are getting this when it tries to render the form, I too am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just

```
<%= form_for information ,:namespace=>'admin' do |f| %>
```

UPDATE:

Look at your routes 'informations' pluralized,  but your using the singular form 'information'

Comment: thank you, but no cigar... still the same error. any other ideas? :)

Comment: can you post the output of 'rake routes', I'm confused as to why it's even trying to look for the index_path???

Comment: Ahh,  look at the path being requested 'admin_information_index_path',  but your routes are 'informations', pluralized!  Just for shits and giggles,  what happenes if you change your routes.rb to 'resources information'

Comment: +1 @RadBrad! Update your answer to include that solution and I'll select it as the chosen answer, since you came up with that before @raiis :)

Answer (score 1):

You must use correct form of controller, because:

'information'.pluralize 

is
"information", not informations.

So, rename controller and view folder.

Comment: Hit it right on its head! Renamed controller to InformationPagesController and model to InformationPage instead of just Information as well as updated all migrations, helpers, tests, routes, et cetera to avoid confusion and voila! it works! Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work... Just a guess.

`form_for @admin.information` or something along those lines.